# Understanding measure-theoretic definition of an n-step transition kernel

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, markov-chains, markov-process

An $n$-step transition kernel is defined as (see e.g. Monte Carlo Statistical Methods by Robert & Casella):
$$
K^n(x, A) = \int_\mathcal{X} K^{n-1}(y, A) K(x, dy)
$$
I am trying to get an **intuitive** understanding of this expression.

Intuitively, I would have thought that the $n$-step transition kernel should look something like this (I know this doesn't make any sense)

$$
K^n(x, A) = \int_{A} K^{n-1}(x, B) K(B, dy)
$$

My reasoning behind this is:

- We use the first $n-1$ steps to move from the initial point $x$ to some point in the set $B$ (any set)
- Then we use the final kernel to move from a point in $B$ to a point $y\in A$.

Something like this (but correct) would make sense to me because it resembles
$$
K(x, A) = \int_A K(x, dy)
$$
much more since it is an integration over $A$ rather than $\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: AAAH I got it! It's the other way around!
$$

$$
- First Step: Go from $x$ to some $y\in \mathcal{X}$ 
$$

$$
- Second Step: Go from $y$ to any point in $A$ in $n-1$ steps
$$

$$
Basically I was trying to write the definition using $K^n = K^{n-1} K$ but they use $K^n = KK^{n-1}$

Comment: Another heuristic short-cut: $K$ has two arguments. One is a point and the other is a set. For $K(B,dy)$ to make sense, $K$ would have to be a measure in both arguments.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Makes sense! Do you know of any resource for learning about measure-theoretic mcmc that explains things also via intuition rather than just mathematical notation?

Comment: I barely know the first thing above mcmc. I'd assume a general introduction to Markov chains/Markov processes would be better for your intuition, though.